# Capture text using Regex that contain line returns with Positive lookbehind and Positive lookahead

Tags: regex-group, regex-greedy

The following accomplishes capturing all the text between Start and Finish
(?<=Start:)(.*?(?=Finish))

Start:This id line 1This id line 2This id line 3Finish

However, I need to capture the following text between Start and Finish that contains line returns.
What parameter do I need to add to (?<=Start:)(.*?(?=Finish)) so I can accomplish this. It also needs to be in the same format for later use. Is this the best method.

As always... thanks

Start:

This id line 1.

This id line 2.

This id line 1.

Finish

I tried (?<=Start:)([^.]+(?=Finish)) but the period at the end of each line caused an issue

Comment: You have to make the dot match a newline with for example an inline modifier if that is supported `(?s)` or `[\s\S]*?` instead of `.*?`